# LMER/GLMER How to generate random effects design matrix?

Tags: r, lme4, toeplitz

Just to illustrate my situation, imagine this is my data:

```
y = rbinom(25, 1, 0.5)
names1 = rep(1:5, each = 5)
names2 = rep(1:5 , 5)
x= rnorm(25)
df = data.frame(cbind(names1, names2, y, x))
```

That is, it looks like the following:

| names1 | names2 | y | x |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 0 | -1.10152733 |
| 1 | 3 | 1 | 1.49929490 |
| 1 | 4 | 0 | 0.96740978 |
| 1 | 5 | 1 | -0.52383757 |
| 2 | 1 | 0 | -1.19182503 |
| 2 | 3 | 1 | 1.00492382 |
| 2 | 4 | 1 | 0.39198228 |
| 2 | 5 | 1 | -0.68029102 |

I want to estimate y here using glmer, ie:

```
glmer(y ~ x + (1|Random), family = binomial, data=df)
```

For my problem, Random effects structure should be based on names, independent of them appearing on names1 or names 2 column. That is, in the general formulation of the model $y=X\beta + Zb +\u$, the matrix Z here is n*p, where in this exercise n=20 (nrow(df)), and p=5 (length(unique(df$names1)). $Z_{ij}=1$ if the name $j$ appear in row $i$, that is names1=j OR names2=j

My question is how can I use this matrix Z as my random effects grouping:

```
glmer(y ~ x + (1|Z), family = binomial, data=df)
```

So far, I have generated Z as:

```
for (i in 1:length(unique(df$names1))) {
     df[paste0("Z", i)] <- ifelse(df$names1 == i | df$names2 == i, 1, 0)
 }
df = df[df$names1 != df$names2,]
```

But i am at lost in how to incorporate Z's in glmer. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have enough reputation to comment or edit, so hopefully someone can merge this into Ben's answer:

[`lmerMultiMember`](https://jvparidon.github.io/lmerMultiMember/) is an R package written specifically to handle this type of multiple membership model. Using it is pretty straightforward, the only reason Ben's example doesn't work is that unlike `lme4`, `lmerMultiMember` *requires* you pass the data in through the `data` argument of the `lmer()` or `glmer()` function call. (This is a technical limitation, unfortunately.)

That means you can't just use variables the model formula when they exist in the top-level R environment, they have to be in the dataframe you pass in through the `data` argument.

The example below works just fine, and does the same thing as Ben's example:

```r
set.seed(101)
y <- rbinom(25, 1, 0.5)
names1 <- rep(1:5, each = 5)
names2 <- rep(1:5, 5)
x <- rnorm(25)
df <- data.frame(names1, names2, y, x) ## better not to cbind() unnecessarily

## if necessary: remotes::install_github("jvparidon/lmerMultiMember")
library(lmerMultiMember)

## create weight matrix for multiple membership model
W <- weights_from_vector(paste(df$names1, df$names2, sep = ","))

## fit model and inspect summary
m <- lmerMultiMember::lmer(y ~ x + (1 | names), memberships = list(names = W), data = df)
print(summary(m))
```

The vignettes at https://jvparidon.github.io/lmerMultiMember/ have some more usage examples that might be of help.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response, and bringing up the data=df

Comment: if one of these answers solved your problem, please click the check-mark to accept it

Answer (score 0):

The name for this setup is a **multi-membership model**.

This can be hacked in `lme4` following the recipe [here](https://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/notes/multimember.html), which I illustrate below. Alternatively, there is an [lmerMultiMember package on Github](https://github.com/jvparidon/lmerMultiMember) which is supposed to fit these models (but I couldn't get it to work, so I show how to do it the hacky way).

### set up data

```r
set.seed(101)
y = rbinom(25, 1, 0.5)
names1 = rep(1:5, each = 5)
names2 = rep(1:5 , 5)
x= rnorm(25)
df = data.frame(names1, names2, y, x) ## better not to cbind() unnecessarily
```

```r
## if necessary: remotes::install_github("jvparidon/lmerMultiMember")
library(lmerMultiMember)
M <- weights_from_vector(paste(df$names1, df$names2, sep = ","))
try(lmerMultiMember::lmer(y ~ x + (1 | names),
                      memberships = list(names = M)))
```

This throws an error for reasons I don't understand. I'll use `M` (which is the transpose of the `Z` matrix) below instead:

```r
library(lme4)
## a fake factor with the right levels, actual values don't matter
fake <- rep(unique(c(df$names1, df$names2)),length.out=nrow(df))
## set up model structures
lmod <- lFormula(y~x+(1|fake), data = df)
## substitute the membership matrix for Z-transpose
lmod$reTrms$Zt <- lmod$reTrms$Ztlist[[1]] <- M
## set up and fit the model
devfun <- do.call(mkLmerDevfun, lmod)
opt <- optimizeLmer(devfun)
m1 <- mkMerMod(environment(devfun), opt, lmod$reTrms, fr = lmod$fr)
```

You can also fit multi-membership models in the `MCMCglmm` package, if you want to go Bayesian ...

Comment: Thank you for your response. I checked out both packages!